# A problem of likelihood function in a dynamic setting?

Tags: bayesian, maximum-likelihood, conditional-probability, hidden-markov-model, quasi-likelihood

I'm having a problem regarding perhaps conditional maximum likelihood problem, but I'm not sure.

Suppose time horizon we consider is $T=4$, our goal is to minimize the loss function
$$
\sum_{t=2}^T L(y_t - u_{t-1} -v_t - \sum_{k=1}^K a_k \phi(u_{t-1}) )
$$
where $\phi$ is some known function. The goal is to estimate parameters $(a_1,\cdots,a_k)$.

More structure is
$$
y_t = u_t + v_t, \forall t= 1,\cdots,T
$$
and
$$
u_t = u_{t-1} + \eta_{t} 
$$
That is, $y_t$ is observed; $u_t, v_t$ are unobserved; $u_t$ is independent of $v_t$; $u_t$ follows a random walk process.

I want to follow other people's work to use likelihood-based method to solve it, but the additive structure poses a challenge.

The likelihood-based objective function is:

$$
argmin_{a_1,\cdots,a_K} = \sum_{t=2}^T E_{y_t} \left[\int L(y_t - u_{t-1}-v_t - \sum_{k=1}^K a_k \phi(u_{t-1})) \cdot f(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,v_1, v_2,v_3,v_4 | y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4)\,du_1 du_2 du_3 du_4 dv_1 dv_2 dv_3 dv_4 \right]
$$

Next, since the density is infeasible ($u$ and $v$ are unobserved), use a Bayesian interpretation, treating the density as "posterior density". Use MCMC to draw those unobserved variables.

However, when applying the Bayes rule I have a problem, the likelihood function becomes
$$
f(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,v_1, v_2,v_3,v_4 | y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4) \propto f(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4 | u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)\cdot f(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4) \cdot f(v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)
$$

However, the first term $f(y_1,y_2,y_3,y_4 | u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,v_1,v_2,v_3,v_4)$ will degenerate to a constant, because once $u_t,v_t$ are controlled, $y_t=u_t+v_t$ is determined.

I figure out a trick to avoid this by replacing the overall density $f(u_1,u_2,u_3,u_4,v_1, v_2,v_3,v_4 | y_1, y_2, y_3, y_4)$ in the integral  by
$$
\prod_{t=2}^T f(u_{t-1},v_t | y_t).
$$
By Bayes rule:
$$
\prod_{t=2}^T f(u_{t-1},v_t | y_t) \propto \prod_{t=2}^T f(y_t | u_{t-1},v_t) \cdot f(u_{t-1}) \cdot f(v_t)
$$

But I'm unsure whether this replacement has any theoretical guarantee? Is it still a likelihood-based problem? I am not sure whether it is related to the concept of conditional likelihood method?

Any reply would be appreciated!

Update:

New idea: for each $t$, use $f(u_{t-1},v_t | y_t)$ in the integral, rather than the overall big density. But in the MCMC produce, to draw values from their product as discussed above!

Comment: Hi: You're making it way more complicated than it is. ( the estimation part ). It's too long for me to try to explain here but if you have Andrew Harvey's  text  https://www.amazon.com/Econometric-Analysis-Time-Harvey/dp/0860031926/ref=sr_1_3?dchild=1&keywords=andrew+harvey+econometrics&qid=1613411360&sr=8-3#customerReviews  it will provide all of the details. Note that if you're really into this area in general, it's worth buying it because it's the only one I know of that goes into the gory details to the level it does. I highly recommend it and used it to do the type of thing you are doing.

Comment: @mlofton, Thanks a lot for the recommendation! I will borrow it from library.

Comment: @mlofton Actually, the model I described is a longitudinal data. For simplicity, I omitted the notation for individual observation. Hope it can be helpful! Thanks agian!

Comment: I don' think harvey considers longitudinal but the concepts he discusses should remain the same for that type of data, I think. he's written quite a few books so make sure you get the one I mentioned and not one of his other ones. the others are good but not as relevant.